# What is the best way to save items into the data base when multiple object items comes as an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am now trying to save multiple data into the database.
What I want to do is I want to save each item inside the array as an object.

eg data

```
[{ "name": "something", "age": 12 },{ "name": "something else", "age": 11 }]
```

What I am doing now is I am looping through the data array and saving them each time.

```
expenseArray.map((expenses) => {
          newExpense = new Expense(expenses);
          newExpense.shop_id = req.params.shop_id;
          newExpense
            .save()
            .then(function (expense) {
              returnArray.push(expense);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              res.status(403).json({ msg: error });
            });
        });
```

The `eg` now is only 2 objects. But what I want to know is if the array comes in as an array of 1000 objects, I am thinking my code will slow down the app. Since i am calling `save` 1000 times.
Is there better ways to tackle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mongoose's [insertMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) instead of looping and manually creating/saving each document. From the docs:

> Shortcut for validating an array of documents and inserting them into
> MongoDB if they're all valid. This function is faster than .create()
> because it only sends one operation to the server, rather than one for
> each document.

You can use it like this:

```
await Expense.insertMany(expenseArray);
```